# message order incorrect (using io_service::wrap)

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I've an application to which a GUI connects and receives a lot of messages and the problem is that every once in a while it receives a message out of order.

The connection runs on a separate worker thread (a separate `io_service`) and exposes the `send` function(which does a `async__write`) via `io_service::wrap` as  a callback for others to invoke with a string message as  parameter. (i.e. `callback = io_service_.wrap(boost::bind(&SomeGUIClass::send,this,_1));`),

so to send something to the GUI client, the others call `callback(stringMessage)` - which should correctly dispatch the send function call on the `io_service`'s queue.

messages are in correct order before invoking the `callback`, but I can see that sometimes they are out of order within the `callback`,just before the write call.

my reasoning: wrap translates to a `dispatch` which will try to call the wrapped fn. within the `callback` (if it can meet the thread safety guarantees) , and schedule it for later if it cannot.
thus sometimes earlier messages get scheduled for a later write and the latest messages get processed since dispatch was able to process it within the same `callback`.
please let me know if this reasoning is correct, any ideas appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it was a bug, and thus the attendant confusion.  (was making the mistake of calling io_service::run from 2 separate threads wihout realising.) now realized, and problem solved. thanks!